# GeoXml3 parse fusion table layer of kml (points) into Google Maps

Tags: google-maps, kml, google-fusion-tables

I have a kml of points loaded into fusion table layer. I want to parse the data to une map.fitBounds on the layer extent using geoxml3, but thats not functionning. This exactly code below is working with KML polygons but not with KML points layer.

Code:

```
    var queryText = encodeURIComponent("SELECT * FROM 1CNJWjLDYgBkJGZVslJ67Fak4DyqadEFuIabzQ60 ");
    var query = new google.visualization.Query('http://www.google.com/fusiontables/gvizdata?tq='  + queryText);

    query.send(zoomTo);
    }

    function zoomTo(response) {
    if (!response) {
      alert('no response');
      return;
    }
    if (response.isError()) {
      alert('Error in query: ' + response.getMessage() + ' ' + response.getDetailedMessage());
      return;
    } 

      FTresponse = response;
      //for more information on the response object, see the documentation
      //http://code.google.com/apis/visualization/documentation/reference.html#QueryResponse
      numRows = response.getDataTable().getNumberOfRows();
      numCols = response.getDataTable().getNumberOfColumns();
      var geoXml = new geoXML3.parser();
      var bounds = new google.maps.LatLngBounds();
      for (var i = 0; i < numCols; i++){
        if (FTresponse.getDataTable().getColumnLabel(i) == 'geometry') {
          var ColIndex = i;
        }
      }
      if (!ColIndex){
        alert('Geometry column "geometry" not found.')
      }
      for (var i = 0; i < numRows; i++){
          var kml = FTresponse.getDataTable().getValue(i,ColIndex);
          geoXml.parseKmlString("<Placemark>"+kml+"</Placemark>");
          bounds.union(geoXml.docs[i].bounds);
      }    

          map.fitBounds(bounds);
    }
```

Comment: Where did you get this code from?  Can you provide a link?  It looks wrong.  The parse method should not be used for parsing KML strings from FusionTables (the parseKmlString method is for doing that).

Comment: Yes you are right, its my mistake. I edited the code. Now its working. thank you! p.s I took this code from your example at www.geocodezip.com. Maybe you could add an example with markers kml in fusiontablelayer.

Comment: I created an [example that decodes KML "Points" from FusionTables using GViz and geoxml3](http://www.geocodezip.com/geoxml3_test/v3_geoxml3_FusionTables_zoomToKmlMarkersA.html), I didn't use your data for 2 reasons: 1. your table is not enabled for download 2. your table has more that 500 rows, and runs into the 500 row limitation on GViz queries.

Comment: Thank you. its a good thing you didnt use my data, I cannot assure it will be online long.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The parse method should not be used for parsing KML strings from FusionTables (the parseKmlString method is for doing that).

```
      var kml = FTresponse.getDataTable().getValue(i,ColIndex);
      geoXml.parseKmlString("<Placemark>"+kml+"</Placemark>");
```

Note: the KML fragments stored in FusionTables do not include the `<Placemark>` tags which geoxml3 looks for, that is why they are added to the string passed to geoxml3.

The GViz query response has a 500 row limit (that doesn't seem to be documented anywhere I could find, the best I could find was this [reference to it](http://osdir.com/ml/google-visualization-api/2011-07/msg00446.html), but the documentation has moved since then).

Looks like you are going to run into that limitation with your table, to overcome that use the [FusionTables API v1.0](https://developers.google.com/fusiontables/docs/v1/getting_started), that returns GeoJSON, not KML (so you will no longer need geoxml3).

[example that decodes KML "Points" from FusionTables using GViz and geoxml3](http://www.geocodezip.com/geoxml3_test/v3_geoxml3_FusionTables_zoomToKmlMarkersA.html) (table contains less than 500 points)

[example of parsing markers from Fusion Tables using the Fusion Tables API v1.0](http://www.geocodezip.com/v3_GoogleEx_FusionTables_generic_JSON_linkto.html?lat=14.620282&lng=-90.504716&zoom=12&type=m&tablequery=SELECT%20%20geometry,%20name,%20description%20FROM&tableid=1npi-QWwoZ6LP_9wwHiwiG2omzMm6R9Qoj5aMjkM)

Comment: Can you provide example on how to parse markers from kml in fusiontable with the new FusionTables API?

Comment: Is it me or the Fusion Table API is very slow in comparizon with Visualization API ? Trying to parse polygon KML is really really slow.